What exactly is a Morita invariant property for rings?
I was reading some research papers on noncommutative rings and oftentimes I read that some property is not Morita invariant. Like this paper said that clean property is not Morita invariant. In one paper I read that Armendariz property of rings is not inherited by matrix rings and hence this property is not Morita invariant.
So I want to ask that if some property is inherited by corner rings and matrix rings then can I say that it is Morita invariant.
Also if the answers are not in terms of category theory it will be easy for me.

Any two isomorphic rings are Morita equivalent. It means if subrings or matrix rings are not Morita invariant means they are not isomorphic as well.

@MuhammadShanu What exactly do you mean by "if subrings or matrix rings are not Morita invariant means they are not isomorphic as well"?  Seems like there are a few ways to interpret it, some of which aren't true...

If $R$ has a property and every ring Morita equivalent to $R$ also has the property, then that property is said to be "Morita invariant." Morita equivalence is, of course, the existence of an equivalence of the categories of right $R$ modules and right $S$ modules (or what turns out to be the same, such an equivalence between their categories of left modules.) That is the category theoretic portion.
It is also known that for any ring $R$ and positive integer $n$, $R\simeq M_n(R)$.
Furthermore given any "full idempotent" of $R$ (meaning the ideal in $R$ generated by $e$ is all of $R$) it is true that $R\simeq eRe$, ($eRe$ is called the corner ring for that idempotent.)
Finally, it turns out this is exhaustive, that if $R\simeq S$, then $S=eM_n(R)e$ for some $n$ and full idempotent $e$ of $M_n(R)$.
From this it's easy to see that a property is Morita invariant iff it is preserved by finite matrix rings and in corner rings using full idempotents.
It is not necessary for it to pass to all corner rings.  For example, using $R=T_2(F)$, the upper triangular matrices over a field, and $e=e_{11}$, you can see that $eRe$ is a field, but "simple ring" is a Morita invariant property, and $R$ is not simple while $F$ is.  So you can't trust a non-full idempotent to preserve Morita invariant properties.
You already gave an example of a property not inherited by matrix rings, and so it cannot be Morita invariant (in that case, $R$ has the property and $M_n(R)$ does not, even though $R\simeq M_n(R)$.)
Right now "clean" is the only property I know of that passes to all matrix rings but doesn't pass to corner rings by full idempotents (which makes it fail Morita invariance.)

Another property that passes to matrix rings but is not Morita invariant is that of being a Frobenius ring.

@JeremyRickard I've wondered about that one.  Do you know where preservation of "Frobenius" in $M_n(R)$ appears in print? I'd like to give a reference in DaRT...  I've already got a full-corner ring demonstrating the breakdown.

I've not been able to find an explicit statement in print, but the proof is not hard. Let $S=M_n(R)$ with $R$ Frobenius. Since "quasi-Frobenius" is a Morita invariant property, $S$ is also quasi-Frobenius. Since $\operatorname{rad}S=M_n(\operatorname{rad}R)$ and $\operatorname{soc}S_S=M_n(\operatorname{soc}R_R)$, $S/\operatorname{rad}S\cong M_n(R/\operatorname{rad}R)\cong M_n(\operatorname{soc}(R_R))\cong\operatorname{soc}(S_S)$.
